# Safe way to upgrade systemd in Xenial?

Tags: 16.04, systemd

Xenial (16.04) has `systemd-229`. Unfortunately, that version seems to still have a bug that prevents `KillUserProcesses` from working properly. [See this bug](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/3483).

So, I want to upgrade to *at least* 230, or even newer.

Since systemd is such a core plumbing to Ubuntu, how do I do this safely?

(edit: fixed version number)

Comment: Safely: You upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu. As a bonus, most of your other software gets a version-bump, too.

Comment: @user535733 No, thanks. There's not yet any LTS version after 16.04.

Answer (score 7):

You have five options. You will need to decide which criteria (LTS, safe, easy, fast) are more important - no option meets all of them:

1. **Wait for the next LTS**. This is safe, but it does not fix your problem.
2. **Install a newer non-LTS release**. This is also safe, but you seem to not like this one.
3. **File a [Stable Release Update](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates)** request on Launchpad to get the fix backported to 16.04. This is reasonably safe - SRUs are well-tested. SRUs take time, and may be rejected entirely by the developers.
4. Try installing a systemd package from a newer release of Ubuntu. This is almost certainly not safe at all, and risks breaking your system horribly.
5. Learn to compile systemd, and install a newer version. This requires great skill and patience to do properly. Many, many opportunities for breakage and frustration, not safe at all unless you have *years* of experience with compiling and init.

Comment: I would NOT install 17.04 and expect to upgrade 17.10 -> 18.04 at this moment, too many changes to call "safe" by any stretch. I would consider a fresh install of 17.10 in a month anticipating an upgrade to 18.04 to be as safe as it gets with the fresh install and upgrade approach.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen agreed. Since the OP already rejected that option, I didn't spend a lot of time qualifying it, nor wandering down the slippery slope of comparative safety. That would be a whole book, eh?

Comment: agreed, but just mentioning the issues as I am guessing the OP has not done much if any research into the changes 17.10 brings.

Comment: @Panther true. There's a reason why I insisted on LTS (in this case, 16.04), because it "should be good" until 2021. I don't have to keep myself constantly up-to-date with "latest and greatest".