# Journald stops with SIGBREAK

Tags: 16.04, crash, systemd-journald

I have poor knowledge of how journald works. I have several questions alongside with the main issue.

I use following `journald` configuration on Ubuntu 16.04 servers

```
[Journal]
Storage=persistent
SystemMaxUse=100G
SystemKeepFree=10G
SystemMaxFileSize=1G
```

Others left [default](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/journal/journald.conf)

Logs are got from docker application. I would like to use max 100G if enough space available on storage and keep 10G free if not. **Didn't I miss something?**

Today I found out that journald is stopped on a number of machines.

```
$ systemctl status systemd-journald
● systemd-journald.service - Journal Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-journald.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: core-dump) since ср 2018-04-11 23:10:32 EEST; 1 weeks 1 days ago
     Docs: man:systemd-journald.service(8)
           man:journald.conf(5)
  Process: 31584 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-journald (code=dumped, signal=ABRT)
 Main PID: 31584 (code=dumped, signal=ABRT)
```

I see no any core dump in `/var/lib/systemd/coredump/`.

All of them has storage < 100G. So, I assumed that logs fill out the space, leave 10G free and after that the oldest one will be deleted (rotated)... and logs accumulating continue. **Am I right?**

But first machine has 4.3G free space, second one 8.3G. There are also machines that have > 10G free where journald stopped.

```
$ systemd --version
systemd 229
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN
```

I thought may be it's possible to [update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966548/safe-way-to-upgrade-systemd-in-xenial?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) `systemd`. But it definitely is not simple like `apt dist-upgrade`.

On one machine before I was able to start `systemd-journald` I had to purge logs.

I'm very glad that 18.04 is coming, but anyway any ideas are appreciated.